Differential Forms and Path Integrals
How to prove this problem from Fulton Book (Algebraic Topology)
Show that an open set U in the plane is connected if and only if there is a segmented path between any two pints of U. Can you show that any two points in a connected open set can be connected by an arc, i.e a path that is one-to-one, and whose tangent never vanishes?

You will have to argue that you can smooth a piecewise-smooth path (e.g., by rounding the corner).
